# How to use adaptive cards in Power Virtual Agents?

Tags: adaptive-cards, power-virtual-agents

I want to use adaptive card in PVA (chat bot).
Tried to create a PVA flow and added an adaptive card.
If I use the flow in "microsoft team" then there is no issue but if I try to use it in PVA,it doesnot work.

[image]

Is there a way to include adaptive cards in PVA flow where we don't have "team id" and "channel id".
Flow structure is created as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to send an Adaptive Card to the user in Power Virtual Agents, you will need to extend the bot using Bot Framework Composer. Inside Composer, it's possible to [respond to the user with an adaptive card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-send-cards).

To achieve this, you will have to return the data that is the input to the adaptive card in Power Automate to Power Virtual Agents. The return value should be a string, and it will get JSON Serialized. Inside Composer, you can JSON deserialize the string using the `json` function. As long as the variable inside of Power Virtual Agents is a bot-scoped variable, you can pass the data:

[image: Output from Power Automate]

[image: Global variable]

[image: Json Parse function]

Here is Microsoft's documentation on [Bot Framework Composer integration with Power Virtual Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-bot-framework-composer).